# Arduino zero programming port recognized as EDBG USB port

Tags: arduino-zero

I am using Arduino Zero with Windows 10. I tried following the procedure listed in [Getting started with Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoZero) to set up my Arduino/environment, however, when I connect the Zero's Programming Port to my laptop's USB 3.0 port, it detects it as **"Atmel Corp. EDBG USB Port"** instead of **"Arduino Zero Prog. Port"** (or something similar) as described under the section "Installing Drivers for the Zero" in the above link. Since it is recognized as an EDBG USB Port, I am unable to burn bootloader or upload sketches using the Programming port as it cannot detect CMSIS-DAP.

when I try to upload a sketch I get the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Zero (Programming Port)"
Sketch uses 23496 bytes (8%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Global variables use 3536 bytes (10%) of dynamic memory, leaving 29232 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 32768 bytes.
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-gf0767a31 (2018-06-11-13:36)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 0
none separate
adapter speed: 400 kHz
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Error: unable to open CMSIS-DAP device 0x3eb:0x2111
Error: No Valid JTAG Interface Configured.
Error: No Valid JTAG Interface Configured.
```

When I try to burn bootloader I get the following error:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-gf0767a31 (2018-06-11-13:36)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 0
none separate
adapter speed: 400 kHz
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Error: unable to open CMSIS-DAP device 0x3eb:0x2111

Error while burning bootloader.
```

**How can I fix this?**

So far, I tried

1. re-installing the IDE several times, and also tried uninstalling the device- but it auto installs the driver when I connect again.
2. Starting IDE as an admin did not help, although I think the issue is the EDBG CMSIS-DAP is not installed, and instead, the EDBG USB driver is installed

Comment: what I would try:  select EDBG programmer in Tools menu and Burn bootloader or Upload with programmerr

Comment: @Juraj, I did select EDBG programmer, chose the right board, and port when I got the error messages.

Comment: is it a genuine Arduino Zero? please add a link to a page where you bought it

Comment: I bought it a while ago and based on the confirmation email, I bought it from Arduino LLC and the email was from  "Arduino Store USA <store-usa@arduino.cc>"

Comment: ok. are you sure the USB cable good?

Comment: Yes, I tried several of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have one of these to test with, but in looking at the driver installation instructions, I would expect it to say "EDBG Virtual COM Port" before a driver is installed and "Atmel Corp. EDBG CMSIS-DAP" after the driver is installed.

The "Arduino Zero Programming Port" is something I expect only appears in the Tools/Port menu in the IDE, despite what it says in the article.  You can see this name given in the boards.txt file.  And this makes sense to me, given that the EDBG firmware is Atmel's not Arduino's and there appears to be no indication in the driver directory, the content of the INF files, to suggest that they they're providing their own customized driver for the programming port.  So I would trust what you see in the images, suggesting it *should* say CMSIS-DAP without mention of "Arduino Zero" at all.  So far as I can tell, you're not doing anything incorrect driver-wise, but I'm also not seeing everything.

In any case, it appears you should have the VID (**03eb**) and PID (**2157**) in the device properties that boards.txt instructs the IDE to look for:

```
arduino_zero_edbg.name=Arduino/Genuino Zero (Programming Port)
  1 arduino_zero_edbg.vid.0=0x03eb
  2 arduino_zero_edbg.pid.0=0x2157
```

However, your error mentions PID=**2111**.  I looked this up in a USB VID/PID database, and it mentions the an ATMEL Xplained board, which is not a completely unrelated thing, but this VID:PID are not mentioned in the driver information or boards.txt for the Arduino Zero.

I did find [this one mention](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=360330.msg2485017#msg2485017) that the Xplained USB PID was used on the [M0 Pro](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-m0-pro) which is a different beast from the [Zero](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-zero).

In any case, I would not worry about not seeing something like "Arduino Zero Prog. Port" in device manager itself for the programming port.

Make sure you are using Zero and not M0 Pro.  **If you have the M0 pro**, in which case properties in Device Manager may show PID as ***2111**, I'm not sure what to suggest except that maybe you should install [Microchip Studio](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/microchip-studio) since this seems to be the only way I can find to get the Xplained EDBG drivers.  Some work may still be required after that to get it to work in the IDE.

If you have a Zero and not M0 Pro installing Microchip Studio may also install the EDBG driver for it as well, although this really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. Although I have retrieved the "board info" multiple times in the past, I just now noticed that it says 

BN: Arduino M0 Pro (Programming Port)
VID: 03eb
PID: 2111
SN: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: @jiggling_electrons, interesting serial number (I assume that's what SN is).  I don't know what to make of that, but yeah, it sounds like you need to use the Xplained Pro driver and who knows what from there.  It *may* be possible for you to alter the PID values the driver .INF and boards.txt file in order to get the IDE to work with it.

Comment: @jiggling_electrons,  Or perhaps better, don't mess with the PID in the INF file.  Instead, get the Xplained driver by installing Microchip Studio (I think),  and then modify boards.txt in order to get the IDE to recognize the board, if necessary, after that.

Comment: @jiggling_electrons, so is it a M0 Pro or a Zero? can you upload over bootloader when you select M0? what was on the invoice? the boards are very similar at first look.

Comment: @Juraj, based on the link pointed by timemage, the board is Zero Pro :(, its programming port says M0 Pro but Native USB is Zero. I am not able to upload even if I select the M0 Pro as the board. I also downloaded the Atmel Studio but I am trying to figure how to upload without an ICE or select the EDBUG. My invoice says Zero.

Comment: @jiggling_electrons, without going into detail I have found a few other things and have other questions.  But it's going to be a back and forth.  If you find me on freenode I'll try to help.  Whatever relevant and useful parts can be written up here, but I suspect there will be a bunch of rabbit holes that would otherwise make a mess of the question and answer.

Comment: post on forum https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=715160.msg4804484#msg4804484

Comment: @timemage, did you get my pings on freenode? we can also discuss instead on discord jiggling_electrons#1370 or in the arduino forum forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=715160.msg4804484#msg4804484, pointed as well by Juraj above.

Comment: I did.  That is where to find me, I just wasn't around at the time.